# passar parametros em uma requisição no retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

estou estudando retrofit e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

estou realizando uma requisição get na url https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

porém ao montar a requisição não consigo adicionar o parametro posts/1

como está meu código:

```
 @GET("posts")
    Call<ModelJson[]> ouvirMensagens(int page);
```

como eu poderia montar a url sem usar um @Query("") montando a url no formato abaixo?

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É um dos primeiros exemplos da [documentação](https://square.github.io/retrofit/):

```
@GET("group/{id}/users")
Call<List<User>> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId);
```

No seu caso:

```
@GET("posts/{page}")
Call<ModelJson[]> ouvirMensagens(@Path("page") int page);
```